# How do I check if an object has a key which contains a given string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to write a script which checks the DOM for elements with particular attributes; If they exist, console out the attribute and the value; Specifically the `role` and `aria` attribute.

```
<body aria-live="assertive" aria-checked="true">
  <form role="search">
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search query" aria-label="Search through site content">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
  </form>
</body>
```

The markup above should yield:

```
Body aria-live: "assertive", aria-checked:"true"

Form role: "search"

Input aria-label: "Search through site content"
```

And this is the script:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
      var jsUcFirst = (str) => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();

      document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function (node) {
        if (node.hasAttribute('role') || checkForAriaFunc(node)) {
          console.dir(document.body.attributes)
          console.log(
            `${jsUcFirst(node.tagName)} role: ${node.getAttribute('role')}, aria: ${checkForAriaFunc(node)}`
          )
        }
      });
    })
```

As you can see in the if statement I am stuck at how to check for the `aria-*` with `checkForAriaFunc` as a placeholder function/pseudo code.

I consoled dir'ed `document.body` and found there is a `attributes` property called `NamedNodeMap` which is an object which contains the following:

[image]

So what is the best way to go about using a method so I can check if the element has any `arias` tags and if so print them all out?
Thanks in advance!

**Update**
Based on Marcus's suggestion I tried this:

```
  function ariaChecker(el) {
    Object.keys(el.attributes).map((property) => {
      if (property.includes('aria')) {
        console.log(property);
      }
    })
  }
```

But getting back undefined!

**Update**
So taking what guest271314 recommended I tried to write my own function using `filter`:

```
 function ariaChecker(el) {
   return Object.entries(el.attributes).filter((property) => {
     var newarr = []
       if (property.includes('aria')) newarr.push(property.toString())
         return newarr
       }).join(' ')
   }
```

But I am getting:

[image]

Comment: You will have to loop through all properties, and check if the property name starts with `aria-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this function for you. It looks for any attribute you want and returns it's value and false when it doesn't exist:

```
function searchNodeAttr(node, search){
  var attrs = node.attributes; 
  if(attrs && attrs.length){
    for( var a in attrs){
      var attr = attrs[a];
      if(attr.nodeType == 2){
        if((new RegExp(search)).test(attr.name)) return attr.value;
         } else break;
     };
     }

  return false;
}
```

Usage in your case:

```
var ariaAttr = searchNodeAttr(node, 'aria-');
if (node.hasAttribute('role') || ariaAttr !== false){
console.log(ariaAttr)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you could just use Object.keys() as in:

```
Object.keys(document.body.attributes).forEach((property) => { ...})
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Well `Object.keys()` won't list all the attributes on DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to `.map()` the `name` property of the `NamedNodeMap` using `RegExp` or `String` methods, return an `Array` of objects where element has `.some()` of the matched attributes with DOM element `tagName` set as property and value set to an array of objects set to `name`, `value` of matched values passed as parameters to the function, `.filter()` `false` array element values using `Boolean`

```js
// `selector`: CSS selector string
// `attrs`: one or more strings or `Array` of attribute `name`s to match
const getAttributes = (selector, ...attrs) =>
// convert `NodeList` to `Array`
[...document.querySelectorAll(selector)] 
// `.filter()` `attributes` property of DOM element
.map(({attributes, tagName
     , _r = RegExp(`${ attrs.flat().join("|")}`)
     , _f = (all = false) => 
         [...attributes].map(({name, value}) => 
         all ? ({name, value}) : name)}) => 
  _r.test(_f().join(" ")) 
  ? ({[tagName.toLowerCase()]: _f(true).filter(({name}) => _r.test(name))}) 
  : false) 
.filter(Boolean);
          
let {selector, attributes} = {selector:"body, body *"
                             , attributes: ["aria", "role"]};
// or `getAttributes("*", "aria" , "role")`
const attrs = getAttributes(selector, attributes); 
console.log(attrs);
```

```html
<body aria-live="assertive" aria-checked="true">
  <form role="search">
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search query" aria-label="Search through site content">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
  </form>
</body>
```